# Reviving someone who died due to a reduction of his maximum hit points

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, character-death, hit-points, resurrection

Some creatures, such as the *Specter* (MM, p. 279), have a feature that reduces a victims maximum hit points:

> **Life Drain.** *Melee Spell Attack:* +4 to hit, reach 5 ft. , one
>   creature. Hit: 10 (3d6) necrotic damage. The target must
>   succeed on a DC 10 Constitution saving throw or its hit point
>   maximum is reduced by an amount equal to the damage taken.
>   This reduction lasts until the creature finishes a long rest. The
>   target dies if this effect reduces its hit point maximum to 0.

Say someone dies from this effect, and his/her companions want to revive the victim. What would, therefore, happen if they tried this with a spell such as *Revivify*, *Raise Dead* or *Resurrection*, neither of which mention a removal of such an effect? (*True Resurrection* would remove the effects, but that's a 9th level spell. Dying from max hit point reduction when you have access to level 9 spells seems unlikely).

*Raise Dead* in particular states:

> This spell doesn’t, however, remove magical diseases, curses, or similar effects; if these aren’t first removed prior to casting the spell, they take effect when the creature returns to life.

Hit points can only assume a value between  0 and the maximum value (PHB, p. 196).

**Would a creature with 0 maximum hit points that is revived therefore return with 0 hit points - alive, but unconscious? Or is it impossible to revive the creature?**